# Can equatorial mounts be used at lower latitudes?

Tags: telescope, amateur-observing

I wanted to order a Celestron 127EQ and I was going through [the manual online](https://s3.amazonaws.com/celestron-site-support-files/support_files/1245780194_powerseekerinst.pdf) and just noticed that the manual says that latitude is adjustable in about a 20-60° range.

> The PowerSeeker equatorial mount can be adjusted from about 20 to 60 degrees (see figure 4-3)

I'm in Costa Rica which means that it's less than 10° latitude. Is the 20-60 limit a hard limit or it can be lower?

By looking at various telescopes equatorial mounts pictures in internet, I think all will have the problem that the counterweight might hit the legs of the tripod if lowering the angle a lot, so it's not like a problem unique to 127EQ.

I have seen that a cellphone can be used to measure this angle so that would not be a problem as long as the mount can physically rotate down to about 10° but I wonder if this setup would not trip the telescope because the center of mass would be too far to the front..... at least while setting up its axis.

Comment: Have a look at the image #9 in the quick setup guide. I don't know if it means you are in the clear or not. Maybe a Skype call to the phone number listed might help, though they may not be in their offices these days. https://s3.amazonaws.com/celestron-site-support-files/support_files/ps_114_127_setup_eng.pdf

Comment: It looks encouraging in the video where they start with the axis horizontal and turn the screw, but then the video cuts and interestingly *the mount is now suddenly at 20 degrees relative to its base!*  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTaAZ.jpg and the video: https://youtu.be/lvuPiQMHwkQ?t=167

Comment: That's interesting.... but the cut does remove some of the important pieces of information. Take a look at this one: https://youtu.be/pJpHPDEqWCk I guess it could be said that it can be as low as 0, but then the counterweight will hit the tripo's legs so it looks like it won't be safe at 10 degrees. :'(

Comment: Oh I see what you mean about the two counterweights. Usually we just tighten one against the other, but you may be able to find two more nuts and lock one very high and the other very low, so that their average position is in the middle. *Interesting situation!* And *very bad for them!* to leave things so ambiguous for such a wide swath of humanity https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p9ma.png

Comment: Keep in mind I'm a newbee.... I was just wondering: that _might_ not be a problem because I could place the tripod in a position so that, say, the north is in a gap between two legs of the tripod.... then the mount (and counterweight) will be able to be lifted to about 10 degrees wirhour issues (even if I have to measure it with a cellphone, or any other mundane trick) and then it is fixed and won't move anymore.... would this be correct?

Comment: I haven't been in front of a telescope tripod in more decades than I'd like to admit :-) other's will chime in soon I'm sure.

Comment: I realized that if I am able to align the mount with a cellphone/other mundane trick, then the telescope is free to move around and then I would have the same movement resctriction as if I were in any other lalitude (hey, if the counterweight will hit a tripod leg, there's not much that can be done then). Will I be looking at things that are too close to the horizon next to 60/180/300° (the directions that the tripod legs would be forced to be for me to make this possible)? I hope there's more stuff to watch. This sounds like a manageable situation. Let's wait for some more feedback.

Comment: I will change the question to make it more generic, related to EQ mounts in general, as I think it does not only apply for 127EQ.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense, that's why I kept my exanple question for context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer myself: Yes, they can. I got a 150mm x 1400mm Newtonian with a EQ mount and I am able to align its axis... even if it had no scale, it can be done with a cellphone (I have already done it... both for pointing north and adjusting latitude).

**WARNING**: Need to be careful that the weight doesn't go off-balance.

Comment: Would you provide the model and brand (for the Newtonian, and mount if bought separately)? Thanks!

Comment: AstroVenture 6"? Everything came in a single package.